# Gap two Sierpinski set?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, measure-theory

Is it consistent to have a set of reals $X$ of size $\aleph_3$ such that for every $Y \subseteq X$, $Y$ has measure zero iff $|Y| \leq \aleph_1$?

Comment: This would require that every $Y\subset X$ with $|Y|=\aleph_1$ be  a Lebesgue-null set and that every $Y\subset X$ with $|Y|=\aleph_2$  be non-measurable, with inner measure 0  and positive outer measure. I dk whether this is consistent.

Comment: (Add to my previous comment): Every uncountable closed set of reals has the cardinal $c$ of the reals. So if $|Y|<c$ then $Y$ has inner measure $0.$